# What is the analytic form of MeijerG in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, mathematica

I know that the official standard formula can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html), but I am having a very hard time simplifying this special case:

```
MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, A}, {}}, x]
```

where $A$ is a positive integer and $x > 0$. What is the analytic form of this function?

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D%2C+%7B%7B0%2C+0%2C+A%7D%2C+%7B%7D%7D%2C+x%5D) returns an expression involving the generalized hypergeometric function and the digamma function.

Comment: "What is the analytic form of this function?" - the Meijer function is **already** an analytic form. You meant to ask if there's a *simpler* form for your Meijer G expression...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let 
$$
f(a,x) = G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,a \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)
$$
Then it is not hard to determine that, for positive $x$,
$$
   f(1,x) = - \mathrm{Ei}(-x)
$$
Additionally, it follows from Mellin-Barnes representation of the Meijer G-function that
$$
     f(a+1, x) = a \cdot f(a,x) - x \partial_x f(a,x) = -x^{a+1} \partial_x \left( x^{-a} f(a, x) \right)
$$
This means that
$$
    x^{-n} f(n, x) = (-1)^n \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d} x^{n-1}} \left( x^{-1} \mathrm{Ei}(-x) \right)
$$
or

$$
    f(n, x) = (-x)^n \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d} x^{n-1}} \left( x^{-1} \mathrm{Ei}(-x) \right)
$$

Verification in *Mathematica*:

```
In[38]:= {MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 7}, {}}, 
   x], (-x)^7 D[ExpIntegralEi[-x]/x, {x, 6}]} /. x -> 1`16

Out[38]= {1348.4143043955619, 1348.41430439556}
```

Comment: who said anything about `a` being an integer! (+1)

Comment: If $a$ is not an integer, then we can interpret this as the differintegral of the exponential integral... :)

Comment: The naive, analytic continuation approach to "fractional" calculus is the best! (I use it all the time in [dimensional regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization))

Comment: @Simon Quoting the OP, 'where A is a positive integer and x>0.`

Comment: @Sasha: So maybe reading isn't my strong suit...

Answer (score 3):

We've seen Mathematica and Maple, so for comparison, here's [SymPy](http://sympy.org/).
Running the IPython console for SymPy version 0.7.1 gives the same answer as `FunctionExpand[MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, A}, {}}, x]]` in Mathematica or ([Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D,%20%7B1,%201%7D%7D,%20%7B%7B0,%200,%20A%7D,%20%7B%7D%7D,%20x%5D))

```
In [1]: from sympy.abc import a

In [2]: hyperexpand(meijerg([],[1,1],[0,0,a],[], x), allow_hyper=True)
Out[2]: 
 a      2  ┌─  ⎛    a, a     │   ⎞                                     
x ⋅Γ(-a) ⋅ ├─  ⎜             │ -x⎟                                     
          2╵ 2 ⎝a + 1, a + 1 │   ⎠                                     
────────────────────────────────── - log(x)⋅Γ(a) + Γ(a)⋅polygamma(0, a)
                     2                                                 
            Γ(-a + 1)                                                  

In [3]: expand(simplify(_))
Out[3]: 
                                    a  ┌─  ⎛    a, a     │   ⎞
                                   x ⋅ ├─  ⎜             │ -x⎟
  log(x)⋅a!   a!⋅polygamma(0, a)      2╵ 2 ⎝a + 1, a + 1 │   ⎠
- ───────── + ────────────────── + ───────────────────────────
      a               a                          2            
                                                a
```

Props to [Tom Bachmann](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/GSoC-2011-Report-Tom-Bachmann%3a-Definite-Integration) for implementing this code. If you want to understand how these reductions are done, it is worth reading [his code](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/_modules/sympy/simplify/hyperexpand.html), [his blog](http://nessgrh.wordpress.com/) and and the references to [Kelly B. Roach's original algorithm](http://www.cybertester.com/data/issac97.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Using Maple, it appears that the function is $\frac{x^A}{A^2} {}_2F_2(A,A; A+1,A+1;-x)$ for integers $A \ge 2$.